# PHP MYSQL update - replace whole word, but not part of it

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Lets say the field name is `bla` and the value `123`

When I do:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET bla = REPLACE (bla, 123, 777)");
```

`123` becomes `777` and it's good

But when I do:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET bla = REPLACE (bla, 1, 777)");
```

I DON'T want `123` to become `77723` but stay `123`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use `REPLACE`, without a `WHERE` clause? What's wrong with:

```
UPDATE table SET bla = 777 WHERE bla = 123;
```